# Why bendy bone segmenting does not work?

Tags: rigging, bones

The first picture is when I haven't yet segmented the bones:
[image]

The second one is when I have segmented (segmented to 16) both two bones:
[image]

As you can see, the bending is still sharp. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your bones don't seem to be displayed as B bones but as sticks. You need to go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As* and choose *B Bone*.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the top bone is "facing" the wrong way. This will be apparent if you set the display mode to *Octahedral*.

All you have to do, is flip the top bone, and parent the bottom bone as "connected".